# Bulk Marketing Email With multiple Sender ( Bulk Email Software vs Own SMTP )

Tags: email, bulk-email, smtp

We are planning for an OTA (Online Travel Agency) comprising of Hotel bookings. We would like to provide each Hotel Registered with us with 'Bulk Marketing Email' sending feature, for example if **xyz** hotel has tie up with us then we will provide option for them to maintain email list and send their newsletters every week from the Dashboard provided to them.

1. In this scenario, whether setting up our own EMail Blaster
   server(SMTP) is preferable or taking service from third party like
   Mailchimp?
2. Is it possible to configure, so that each hotel can use their own '**From**' email id?

Comment: [Update]Each Service provider has an option to add 'sub-user' which would help you to configure different 'From' email id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend doing this on your own.

The services, like MailChimp, specialize in making sure your e-mails get delivered to their intended recipients. It's their business to make sure as many people see your e-mails as possible, so they take great care to ensure that messages sent through them are not marked as spam.

There's no point in running this through your own SMTP server, if many of those e-mails are just going to get marked as spam/bulk mail, and go to a person's spam folder.

Providers like MailChimp would know the ins and out of mail providers like Hotmail/Outlook, Gmail, Yahoo, Aol, etc, much better than you can figure out on your own, so have a much better chance at getting your message seen.

Another thing to consider is what happens if a user reports your e-mail as spam. If you use your own SMTP server to send these out, and some users mark them as spam and your SMTP server gets temporarily blocked by any of the mail providers, you would not be able to send any e-mail to any users of that provider from your SMTP server. That could be receipts, order info, or other important information you are trying to send out. If your SMTP server gets blacklisted it will impact all of your mail.

Using a third-party provider for bulk mailings can avoid many of these problems.

If you wanted to deliver paper flyers/advertisements to your clients, you'd use the postal service because that's what they specialize in, you wouldn't drive around and deliver them all on your own.

This question has been asked before, with several answers posted that you may find helpful: [Sending Bulk Email/Newsletter (20,000 emails) - our SMTP server vs bulk provider, what software, etc](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11863/sending-bulk-email-newsletter-20-000-emails-our-smtp-server-vs-bulk-provider?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks @Sherwin for detailed explanation :) maintaining own server seems risky and lot of overhead involved. But again,  need to check what option is economically viable.