# Do I need to 'warm up' my email address when I plan on using amazon SES to send bulk email?

Tags: email, spam, amazon-aws, marketing, bulk-email

I've read that when you plan on sending bulk email from a private SMTP server you first need to warm up the IP address of this server by sending only small but incremental amounts of emails in the beginning.

If you don't do that and immediately start sending large amounts of bulk emails then you run the risk of getting black listed by the email providers that receive these emails. In other words: All sent bulk emails will end up in the spam folder by default.

I won't use a private SMTP server so I don't have to warm up any IP address. Instead I plan on using Amazon SES to send email blasts. I've read in [this thread](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/11865/93577) that it is best to use specialized bulk email services such as MailChimp and SilverPop to send bulk email and `the main reason for this is that their antispam whitelisting`.

Like MailChimp and SilverPop, Amazon SES can be considered a bulk email service as well.
My question is: **Is Amazon SES 'antispam whitelisted' as well and can I start sending large amounts of emails immediately  or do I need to start with sending small amounts first to prevent my email address from getting blacklisted?** I plan on sending both cold email blasts as well as newsletters or notification emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon SES documentation says the following about this: `When you create a new Amazon SES account, by default your emails are sent from IP addresses that are shared with other SES users` [(source)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/dedicated-ip.html). So i guess the ip address i'm using is already warmed up.